# scheme of finite type - geometric interpretation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I'm using the definitions given in Qing Liu's Book:

> A morphism $f : X \to Y$ is said to be of finite type if $f$ is
>   quasi-compact, and if for every affine open subset $V$ of $Y$,
>   and for every affine open subset $U$ of $f^{-1}(V)$, the canonical homomorphism
>   $\mathcal O_Y(V) \to \mathcal O_X(U)$ makes $\mathcal O_X(U)$ into a finitely generated $\mathcal O_Y(V)$-algebra. A
>   $Y$-scheme is said to be of finite type if the structural morphism is of finite type.

Now what is the geometric interpretation of a scheme (e.g. a curve or a fibered surface) that is not of finite type? I just see that `of finite type` seems a nice property that one should have, like for example `reduced` or `separated`.

Kind regards, reinbot

Answer (score 2):

Let's decipher a little.

A scheme $X$ over $k$ is of finite type if for every affine $U \subset X$, the morphism $k \to \mathscr O_X(U)$ makes $\mathscr O_X(U)$ into a finitely generated $k$-algebra, but these correspond to **affine varieties** sitting inside some $\mathbb A^n$.

Thus if a scheme is **not** of finite type over $k$, it's affine opens cannot be thought of as living inside $\mathbb A^N$, sothey are not very "geometrical".

Comment: My original question comes from this: Over a non-excellent scheme you can find 'curves' whose normalization is not of finite type (Akizuki's example http://mathoverflow.net/questions/83626/is-the-normalisation-of-an-integral-noetherien-dimension-one-ring-a-finite-morph). 
So this normalization is now no longer a curve?